# Создание дистрибутива RCP приложения посредством Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven

Коллеги

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При построении Eclipse RCP приложения при помощи maven + tycho созданное приложения падает при старте с ошибкой :

```
!SESSION 2017-09-13 13:32:10.129 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-13 13:32:12.185
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

В чем может быть причина такого поведения, куда копать?

То же самое приложение, если делать экспорт из Eclipse, запускается нормально

исходный текст Pom.xml который отвечает за создание развёртывания приложения выглядит так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.psl.atom</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.psl.atom.parent</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.psl.atom</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.psl.atom.product</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>materialize-products</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>materialize-products</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>archive-products</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>archive-products</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: В принципе удалось частично разрешить проблему. Одна из причин оказалась в неправильной генерации файла config.ini в каталоге configuration. Следующие плагины не стартовали  org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar - org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230.jar - org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar - org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850.jar - org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.400.v20160506-0750.jar вопрос осталось в том как наладить правильную генерацию файла config.ini

Comment: Проблема решилось просто в одном из maillist был найден рецепт   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>такую секцию следует добавить в конфингурацию продукта